# Retrieving running totals from two separate tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to perform a running total query based on two tables and I'm a bit stumped. Here is what I have thus far. Firstly let me provide you guys with a DDL of the table and the sample data that I'm using.
Table 1

```
create table Actuals
(
f_year varchar(02),
f_period varchar(02),
f_fund varchar(06),
f_org varchar(06),
f_pror varchar(06),
f_trans_amt decimal

);
```

Table 2

```
create table Actuals
(
f_year varchar(02),
f_period varchar(02),
f_fund varchar(06),
f_org varchar(06),
f_pror varchar(06),
f_trans_amt decimal

);

    GO
    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[Actuals] ([f_year], [f_period], [f_fund], [f_org], [f_pror], [f_trans_amt]) VALUES (N'07', N'01', N'aaa', N'bbb', N'ccc', CAST(20 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[Actuals] ([f_year], [f_period], [f_fund], [f_org], [f_pror], [f_trans_amt]) VALUES (N'07', N'02', N'aaa', N'bbb', N'ccc', CAST(30 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[Actuals] ([f_year], [f_period], [f_fund], [f_org], [f_pror], [f_trans_amt]) VALUES (N'07', N'03', N'aaa', N'bbb', N'ccc', CAST(50 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[Actuals] ([f_year], [f_period], [f_fund], [f_org], [f_pror], [f_trans_amt]) VALUES (N'07', N'04', N'aaa', N'bbb', N'ccc', CAST(150 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
    GO
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[budget] ([f_year], [f_period], [f_fund], [f_org], [f_pror], [f_trans_amt]) VALUES (N'07', N'03', N'aaa', N'bbb', N'ccc', CAST(150 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[budget] ([f_year], [f_period], [f_fund], [f_org], [f_pror], [f_trans_amt]) VALUES (N'07', N'06', N'aaa', N'bbb', N'ccc', CAST(150 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
GO
```

These are my current results using the  following query.

```
with cte_actuals(
totalActual,
f_year,
f_period,
f_fund,
f_org,
f_pror
)
 as (
select sum(f_trans_amt) over (partition by f_fund,f_org,f_pror order by f_period, f_year ) totalActual,
f_year,
f_period,
f_fund,
f_org,
f_pror
from Actuals),

cte_budget (
totalBudget,
f_year,
f_period,
f_fund,
f_org,
f_pror
)
 as (
select sum(f_trans_amt) over (partition by f_fund,f_org,f_pror order by f_period, f_year ) totalBudget,
f_year,
f_period,
f_fund,
f_org,
f_pror
from budget)
select  
b.totalBudget,
a.totalActual,
a.f_year,
a.f_period,
a.f_fund,
a.f_org,
a.f_pror
From
cte_actuals a
full outer join cte_budget b on( a.f_fund = b.f_fund
 and a.f_org = b.f_org
 and a.f_pror = b.f_pror
 and a.f_year = b.f_year
and a.f_period = b.f_period
and a.f_year = b.f_year);
```

[image]

I'm trying to get these results but I'm having a hard time conceptualizing the solution.
[image]

My end goal is to join the two running totals into one query but the tables are not are exact match. In other words not every f_period and f_year are in both tables, so I'm left to fill the blanks with the running total from the last period. The picture above shows the end result of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this, I joined the tables in cte first, then calculate the running total.

```
;with cte as(
select 
     Coalesce(a.f_year, b.f_year) as f_year
    ,coalesce(a.f_period, b.f_period) as f_period
    ,coalesce(a.f_fund, b.f_fund) as f_fund
    ,coalesce(a.f_org, b.f_org) as f_org
    ,coalesce(a.f_pror, b.f_pror) as f_pror
    , Coalesce(a.f_trans_amt, 0) as ActualAmount
    ,coalesce(b.f_trans_amt, 0) as BudgetAmount
 from Actuals as a
 full outer join Budget as b on 
( a.f_fund = b.f_fund
 and a.f_org = b.f_org
 and a.f_pror = b.f_pror
 and a.f_year = b.f_year
and a.f_period = b.f_period
and a.f_year = b.f_year)
) select *
,sum(ActualAmount) over (partition by f_fund,f_org,f_pror order by f_period, f_year ) as ActualAmount
,sum(BudgetAmount) over (partition by f_fund,f_org,f_pror order by f_period, f_year ) as BudgetAmount

 from cte
```

Comment: You my friend are a genius! Thanks for the elegant solution. I was truly stuck there for a while. I'm certainly grateful.